# Code not showing on github (only pages that gets comitted)

Tags: git, github

I have an existing project that I'm trying to add to github thought the terminal on mac.

So this is what I did:

```
echo "# hejhej" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/NewRepo.git
git push -u origin master
```

Does not give any errors but I am only able to see the Pages I've created but not the code (only the default code in a fresh project).

Anyone experienced this too? Thanks

Comment: did you commit your code?

Comment: You can try using `git status` after you've added some files to see what's being committed.
It looks like you may have only added the README.md file and not any code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `git add README.md`

You only added `README.md`.

- `git status` will show you a list of files which are not committed
- use `git add <...>` to ass your files
- push changed to your GitHub repo

[image]

---

In more detailed:

Before you can `push` code to a remote repository you have to **commit** it locally and then push it

In order to **commit** locally you first have to add your files so you will need to execute `git add .` and afterward you can commit and push

#### To view files in the commit

In order to verify which file are committed use this command:

`git whatchanged`

[image]

Comment: No, I actually added the code the first time i comitted. I tried again and added the README.md but no change. Like I said: I can see the view's, viewmodels etc. @CodeWizard

Comment: When I use "git status" I get this: "Changes not staged for commit" @CodeWizard

Comment: Exactly so you need to add them and then commit and push

Comment: So for example "git add FindApp.iOS" ?@CodeWizard

Comment: yep, exactly. and then `git status`

Comment: Thanks alot! @CodeWizard